# How to retrieve airflow pool value in DAG

Tags: airflow

I am using a PostgresHook and need to specify `limit` in sql query equal to the pool value defined in airflow. How can I access that in DAG, so I can template my query to something like:

```
query = select id from accounts 
        where status=1 
        order by create_date 
        limit {{ Pools.get(pool_name) }}
```

Comment: I don't think `pool` is available as one of the default values. You should be able to do that through `params` though

Comment: The pool functionality is really only used to throttle Airflow connections. Maybe a Variable would be better suited for your use?

Comment: yes, but I want to use that same value to limit records in query.

Comment: Just wondering if I there is a way to get that pool value so I don’t have to create a variable.